# How to discover mutual guilds?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list<> of Guilds containing a list<> of Users. Both  and  types have an ID property.

I would like to discover all Users sharing the same Guilds as myself (except the one in question; which we would obviously share)

Is there a smart linq and/or lambda technique to achieving this?

Comment: You will have to describe how you store the guilds and users first? In a database? In a `List<>`? If so how?

Comment: List<> or IReadOnlyCollection<> to be specific

Comment: All the same guilds as yourself? Or can they be in less/more guilds?

Comment: They can be more or less. I will 100% of the time be in the specific Guild.Users list. I am interested in all the occurrences when I share more than 1 guild with a user. My user is in _client.CurrentUser.ID. The lists are within _client.Guilds[].Users[]

Comment: Sorry guy I have no idea what are you talking about do you have some example code?

Comment: @HenkHolterman but does he mean [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) or a class called `Guild` that represents guilds in a game for example? The question is unclear but I took a shot at it anyways.

Comment: Yes, I misread that as Guid. But the complaint stands, the question is far from clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pretty unclear. Still, I took a shot at it. If I have understood correctly:

You have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class Guild
{
    public List<User> Users;
    public int ID;
}
```

And two lists:

```
var guilds = new List<Guild>();
var myGuilds = new List<Guild>();
```

And what you want is all the users of all guilds you are also a part of. You could use this:

```
var guildUsers = new HashSet<User>((from first in guilds
                                    join second in myGuilds
                                    on first.ID equals second.ID
                                    select first.Users).SelectMany(x => x)).ToList();
```

What we are doing here is the following:

Fist, we intersect the two lists based on ID and we select their respective `Users` lists:

```
from first in guilds
join second in myGuilds
on first.ID equals second.ID
select first.Users
```

Then, we use `SelectMany` to flatten the enumeration of lists:

```
.SelectMany(x => x)
```

Then we wrap all this up in a [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) to remove the duplicate users (users that were in multiple guilds).

Finally, we convert the `HashSet` to a `List<User>` (optional).

Answer (score 1):

Comments inside:

```
    public List<User> FindSimilarUsers(List<Guild> lGuilds, List<Guild> MyGuilds)
    {
        // phase 1: map user to his guilds
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> dUserToGuilds = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        lGuilds.ForEach(guild => guild.Users.ForEach(user => dUserToGuilds[user.ID] = new List<int>()));
        lGuilds.ForEach(guild => guild.Users.ForEach(user => dUserToGuilds[user.ID].Add(guild.ID)));

        // phase 2: map user id to corresponding user object
        Dictionary<int, User> dUsers = new Dictionary<int, User>();
        lGuilds.ForEach(guild => guild.Users.ForEach(user => dUsers[user.ID] = user));

        // phase 3: find similar users
        List<int> MyGuildsIds = MyGuilds.Select(guild => guild.ID).ToList();
        return dUserToGuilds.Keys.ToList().Where(user_id => dUserToGuilds[user_id].Intersect(MyGuildsIds).Count() > 1).Select(user_id => dUsers[user_id]).ToList();
    }
```

And a tester:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Guild> lGuilds = new List<Guild>();
        List<Guild> MyGuilds = new List<Guild>();

        User u1 = new User { ID = 1 };
        User u2 = new User { ID = 2 };
        User u3 = new User { ID = 3 };
        User u4 = new User { ID = 4 };
        Guild g1 = new Guild { ID = 1, Users = new List<User>() { u1, u2, u4 } };
        Guild g2 = new Guild { ID = 2, Users = new List<User>() { u1, u3, u4 } };
        Guild g3 = new Guild { ID = 3, Users = new List<User>() { u2, u4 } };
        lGuilds.Add(g1);
        lGuilds.Add(g2);
        lGuilds.Add(g3);
        MyGuilds.Add(g1);
        MyGuilds.Add(g2);

        FindSimilarUsers(lGuilds, MyGuilds).ForEach(user => Console.WriteLine(user.ID));

        // output:
        // 1
        // 4
    }
```